# What is the purpose of DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray

Tags: ember-data

Can someone explain me what is the purpose of immutable DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>AFAIK it is not immutable.</strike> It is a *promise* returned by the `find` method and will be filled with records returned from server. Unfortunately, there is not much documentation right now, but you can read more in [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/record_arrays/adapter_populated_record_array.js).

#### Edit

It is immutable..